# How to make an environment variable be set every time I log in into linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

I have these lines being executed every time I open the bash terminal:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

This is because I placed these lines in the `.bashrc` file.
So every time I open the terminal I have to type in the password for `sudo`.

I'd like these two lines to be executed only once (that is, the first time I open the bash terminal after I have logged in in Ubuntu 18.04).

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
if [ $SUDO_AUDIO_ISSUE -ne 0 ]; then
    echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller
    echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
    SUDO_AUDIO_ISSUE=0
fi
```

But, by doing that, I would need to create and set the environment variable `SUDO_AUDIO_ISSUE` in some place. And this setting should be run only once after I have logged in.

So that's why I'd like to know how to an environment variable be set every time I log in into linux.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in `/etc/profile`?

Comment: it's better to make module settings permanent using configuration files or kernel parameters like in this article: https://major.io/2019/03/04/stop-audio-pops-on-intel-hd-audio/. Unless you are doing some hacking / debugging on it, which I suppose you are not.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for a system startup file, as it applies to the *machine*, not any particular user *of* the machine, even if you are the only user.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to your Linux machine, the file `.profile` (mind the dot, it's a hidden file) in your home directory gets executed automatically.

In order to find that file, just type `cd` (without any parameters), and you'll be directed to the directory where that file should be/is located.

Comment: In bash, likely `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc`. Research both to understand the differences.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not executed by a login shell itself, unless it is indirectly sourced by whatever file (e.g., `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bash_login`) *is* sourced by the shell on startup.